# Code Clarification on Swing Components

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making a JFrame by extending my class to JFrame. And in my constructor I have this code

```
public MyUI() {
    this.setSize(400, 400);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Calculator");


    JTextField textField1 = new JTextField("test", 15);
    JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Tell me something");
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Click Me");

    button1.setToolTipText("Bla");
    thePanel.add(label1);
    thePanel.add(button1);
    thePanel.add(textField1);

    this.add(thePanel);
}
```

However, nothing shows up. But if I comment out the

```
JTextField textField1 = new JTextField("test", 15);
thePanel.add(textField1);
```

everything acts normally. What's the problem of my code?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]. How do you run the program? Do you create the UI in the Swing thread? etc.

Comment: @assylias okay I will next time. My question is already answered below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are displaying your `JFrame` (`setVisible(true)`), **before** adding the components.

So either :

call `setVisible(true)` only once all the components have been added.

Or call :

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

to tell the `JFrame` to recompute its layout, and repaint itself.

I have no clue however, as of why commenting the textfield part out, makes the `JFrame` display correctly, maybe it is related to the components layout.